# call google map api in netlogo and integrate google map in logo

Tags: gis, netlogo

How can we integrate google map and call data through google api in netlogo. I have studied about GIS and KML extension but could not able to find good solution for it.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve? What have you currently tried? Without that information as a starting point, it will be difficult to provide you with support. Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: I want to load the google map and generate route iin netlogo

Comment: You'll need to write a NetLogo extension that calls the API. You can write the extension in Java or in another JVM language such as Scala.

Comment: One more question, how can i import google map in netlogo

Comment: ask a separate question on that? the Stack Overflow format is to ask one question at a time